# Jquery seach all tags with special class if one of them has the value show only one alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[At first visit my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qCC8N/)

When the `submit` button is being clicked if the text `input` field are unchanged `alert` appears. And the text `input` gets red border.

What I want is, how many `input` field is unchanged that doesn't matter, there will be only one `alert` to appear.

Here is my Jquery approach:

```
$(".submit").click(function (e) {
      $(".textInput").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "input here") {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).css({
                border: "1px solid #f00",
                color: "#f00"
            });
            alert("Please input the texts in red box");
        } else {
            $(this).css({
                border: "1px solid #DCDCDC",
                color: "#000"
            });
        }
      });
});
```

How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: `return false;` just after `alert()` to break `each` loop  http://jsfiddle.net/qCC8N/3/

Comment: @A.Wolff- But now the the whole loop (including border and text color) is getting changed one by one. I want the alert to work only like that. thanks

Comment: You are right, I misread your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to aggregate your answer before performing the alert:

```
$(".submit").click(function (e) {
    var doAlert = false; // don't alert, unless the condition sets this to 'true'
    $(".textInput").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "input here") {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).css({
                border: "1px solid #f00",
                color: "#f00"
            });
            // instead of performing the alert inside the "loop"
            // set a flag to do it once the "loop" is complete.
            doAlert = true;
        } else {
            $(this).css({
                border: "1px solid #DCDCDC",
                color: "#000"
            });
        }
    });
    if(doAlert) { // do the alert just once, if any iteration set the flag
        alert("Please input the texts in red box");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sth like that would help with a flag variable:

```
$(".submit").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var error = false;

    $(".textInput").each(function () {

        if ($(this).val() === "input here") {


            $(this).css({
                border: "1px solid #f00",
                color: "#f00"
            });

            error = true;

        } else {
            $(this).css({
                border: "1px solid #DCDCDC",
                color: "#000"
            });
        }        
    });
    if(error == true) alert("Please input the texts in red box");
```

});

Answer (score 0):

just initiate a variable for example Count

and when your condition  ($(this).val() === "input here") is true make it counter by 1 i-e Count+=1;

and in the end put one condition if  (Count>0){ alert("Please input the texts in red box");}

Answer (score 0):

While you've already accepted an answer, I'd suggest a simpler approach:

```
$(".submit").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    /* 1. gets the input elements,
       2. sets their border-color back to that specified,
       3. filters the collection, keeping only those elements without a value,
       4. sets the border-color of only those empty inputs to red,
       5. assigns the length property of the collection to the variable.
    */
    var empties = $('.textInput').css('border-color', '#ccc').filter(function () {
        return !this.value;
    }).css('border-color', 'red');
    // if the length is greater than zero, triggers the (single) alert:
    if (empties.length) {
        alert('please fill out the red-boxes');
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qCC8N/4/).